# Why doesn’t url rewrite work in server

Tags: asp.net, url

In asp.net 3.5, I'm rewriting the url

```
    http://www.dotoobeta/blogs/1108
```

to the following

```
    http://www.dotoobeta/blogs/blogs.aspx
```

I am using the `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll` and it works fine locally, but it is not work on my other server.  I already modified the configuration in IIS also.

What is the solution?

Comment: Which IIS version is installed in the server, if IIS 7 - ASP.NET works on it in Classic or Integrated mode?

Comment: what do you mean by rewriting a url? you want to redirect to another site address?

Comment: i am using  iis 6  .   rewriing means  i am only  rewrite  path only 
 means http://www.dotoobeta/blogs/ blogs.aspx to http://www.dotoobeta/blogs/1108 page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your server is not configured to route requests like http://www.dotoobeta/blogs/1108 through ASP.NET pipeline. If you have IIS 6 or higher on the server, you can configure wildcard handler and handle everything via ASP.NET. Don't forget to uncheck "verify that file exists" checkbox, or it won't work for nonexisting paths.

Comment: we also  configure wildcard handler and han
dle everything via ASP.NET   and also  verify that file exists" checkbox   still now not work

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and it's caused by architecture. I must add mapping for 64 bit too like this :

```
  <add name="aspnet_isapi"    path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="aspnet_isapi-64" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
```